# VB.net Listview, I have an error when selecting after scrolling. Withour scrolling all works fine

Tags: vb.net, listview, select, scroll

I have a `listview` where I set each row with a tag value that represents the record ID.  I use the `ItemSelectionChanged` event and  `e.item.tag` to extract the ID of the selected record.
All works fine unless you need to scroll, once I go past the 31st row, selecting any row beyond that point will only return the id of the last row that was available to view before scrolling. If I then select again then it gets the correct ID. What’s going wrong?  I am using V`B.net 4.5.2` with `Visual Studio 2013`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

The list view was aligned to the left when it was broken, with a splitter bar and details panel on the right in fill mode. I removed the details panel and changed the listview to fill rather than left.  This fixed my problem. I have no clue why, but it works now.